# Ошибки при использовании функций из dll

Tags: c++

У меня есть своя dll библиотека, где `.h` файл:

```
// StringAPI.h
#ifdef STRINGLIBRARY_API
#define STRINGLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define STRINGLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class STRINGLIBRARY_API String
{
/* ... */
public:
    STRINGLIBRARY_API friend String operator+(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    STRINGLIBRARY_API friend String operator+(const String& lhs, char c);
    friend bool operator>(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    friend bool operator>=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    friend bool operator<(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    friend bool operator<=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    friend bool operator==(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);
    friend bool operator!=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs);

    STRINGLIBRARY_API friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& str);
    STRINGLIBRARY_API friend String& operator>>(std::istream& stream, String& str);

};
```

У меня не получается добавить `STRINGLIBRARY_API` другим `friend` функциям. Почему? И из-за этой проблемы я не могу использовать эти методы там, куда я подключаю эту библиотеку. Например:

```
// main.c
#include "StringAPI.h"
int main()
{
    String a("Hello");
    String b("World");
    bool c = a > b;
}
```

И тут я получаю LINK error:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator>(class String const &,class String const &)" (??O@YA_NABVString@@0@Z) referenced in function _main`

Comment: *"не получается добавить STRINGLIBRARY_API другим friend функциям"* Какая-то ошибка возникает? Какая?

Comment: Что значит "не получается добавить"? Клавиши на клавиатуре перестают нажиматься? И к какому коду относится ваше `LNK2019` - к тому, который вы привели? И как насчет остальных `friend`? Например `operator +`? С ними все в порядке?

Comment: @AnT я сейчас добавил `STRINGLIBRARY_API` к остальным функциям и все заработало. Однако компилятор VS подчеркивает теперь эти функции как функции, у которых нет определения, хотя они есть. Это меня и смутило, поэтому я даже не пытался компилировать.

Comment: **Компилятор** ничего не подчеркивает... Давайте наконец отделять среду (пусть и достаточно сложную) от компилятора.

Comment: @Harry я оговорился, но вы поняли, что я имел в виду.

Comment: "... поэтому я даже не пытался компилировать" - ужос!

Comment: Именно потому что я понял, я и пытаюсь внушить мысль - то, что делает и подчеркивает **среда** - это совсем не **компилятор**. Без процесса компиляции и диагностики **компилятора** говорить об ошибках в коде несколько преждевременно.